# Compare two dates without a year

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datetime

I would like to compare two dates excluding years.

Ex.

Input: FromDate: 01 March, ToDate: 05 March

then all records between these two dates should be come whether there is any year. It does not matter.

So please anyone can help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you asking for a LINQ query, a SQL query, ... ?

Comment: I am using EF - @GrantWinney

Comment: IQueryable, IEnumerable? ActionResult, helper method?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LINQ and you want to create a list from querying the db you could do this?

```
    public IEnumerable<Item> WithinTimeRange(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
    {
        var items = from a in context.Items
                    where a.Timestamp.Month.Equals(begin.Month) && a.Timestamp.Day 
        >= begin.Day && a.Timestamp.Month.Equals(end.Month) && a.Timestamp.Day <= end.Day
                    select a;

        return items.ToList();
    }
```

Personally I would create this method in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you don't specify language and place where it will be used, I just give ju a hint.
Convert every datetime to a integer as: `10000 + 100 * month + day` e.g.: 10306 as today.
Then you can ask for every data between `10301` and `10305` from your question.